# Types unmatch VHDL code at Simulation on Modelsim, inspite of thorough check

Tags: types, simulation, vhdl, modelsim

I am requesting some help because I am completly stuck in my VHDL project, consisting in implementing a cartesian to polar convertor on Nios II. All of my VHD files do compile without error, but when I want to simulate the whole block on Modelsim, here is what I get

```
# Loading work.counter(a)
# ** Failure: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "rn".
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /bench_conversor/uut/compt File: C:/Users/Sandjiv/Desktop/test_VHDL/counter.vhd Line: 23
# ** Failure: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "thetan".
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /bench_conversor/uut/compt File: C:/Users/Sandjiv/Desktop/test_VHDL/counter.vhd Line: 24
# Fatal error in file C:/Users/Sandjiv/Desktop/test_VHDL/counter.vhd
#  while elaborating region: /bench_conversor/uut/compt
# Load interrupted
```

This should be easy errors to spot, but I have checked a thousand times my types, they all seem to match. Here follow the codes of counter, conversor (the whole block) and its bench. Once again they all compile, but I get these errors only at simulation on Modelsim.

COUNTER.VHD

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;


entity COUNTER is
port ( counter_en : in std_logic;     --BESOINS???          
       rn : out signed(31 downto 0);
       thetan : out signed(31 downto 0);        
       Etheta : out std_logic;
       SD : in std_logic;
       CLK,RESET : in std_logic);      
end COUNTER;



architecture A of COUNTER is

signal theta : signed (31 downto 0);
signal r : signed (31 downto 0);


begin   

process(CLK,RESET)
begin -- process

     -- activities triggered by asynchronous reset (active high)
     if RESET = '1' then
         r <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
         theta <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
         Etheta <= '0';  

     -- activities triggered by rising edge of clock

     elsif CLK'event and CLK = '1' then

    if counter_en = '1' then


      if SD = '1' then

                if theta /= "000000000000000000000000000000010" then            --VALUE THAT CAN BE CHANGED : THETA_MAX = 4095

                      Etheta <='0';

                      if r = "00000000000000000000000000001000" then              --VALUE THAT CAN BE CHANGED : RMAX = 2000

                         r <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
                         theta <= theta + "0000000000000000000000000000001";

                         else

                         r <= r + "00000000000000000000000000000001";

                         end if;

                    else 

                         theta <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
                         Etheta <= '1'; 

                    end if;

                 else

           theta <= theta;
           r <= r; 
                     Etheta <= '0';

                 end if;   

              else
                   r <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
         theta <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
         Etheta <= '0';  

              end if;         

           end if;

  rn <= r;
  thetan <= theta;


end process;



end A;
```

CONVERSOR.VHD

```
library IEEE ;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL ;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.ALL;




    entity CONVERSOR is

generic 
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 16384000;
        ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 32
    );

    port(   
        CLK     : in STD_LOGIC ;
        RESET_Main  : in STD_LOGIC ;
        Conversor_en        : in STD_LOGIC; 
        Conversor_end : out STD_LOGIC) ;
end CONVERSOR;


    architecture A of CONVERSOR is




component FSM is
    port(   
      Clk           : in STD_LOGIC ;
        Reset_main      : in STD_LOGIC ;
        Conversion_en : in STD_LOGIC;
        RAM_out : in SIGNED(31 downto 0);
        Etheta : in STD_LOGIC;

        Reset           : out STD_LOGIC ;
        WR          : out STD_LOGIC ;
        SD          : out STD_LOGIC ;   
        counter_en          : out STD_LOGIC ;
RAM_in : out SIGNED(31 downto 0)
);
end component;


    component SINGLE_PORT_RAM is
    port 
    (
        clk     : in std_logic;
        addr    : in integer range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        data    : in signed((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        we      : in std_logic := '1';
        q       : out signed((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)
    );

end component;



 component SINGLE_PORT_ROM is
    port 
    (
        clk     : in std_logic;
        addr    : in integer range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        q       : out signed((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)
    );

end component;


  component COUNTER is
port ( 
       counter_en : in std_logic;               
       rn : out signed(31 downto 0);
       thetan : out signed(31 downto 0);    
       Etheta : out std_logic;
       SD : in std_logic;
       CLK,RESET : in std_logic);     

end component;

    component ADDRESS is
port ( 
 sin : in signed(31 downto 0); -- sinus from ROM
       cos : in signed(31 downto 0); -- cosinus from ROM
       r : in signed(31 downto 0);  
       theta : in signed(31 downto 0); --theta from counting block  
      SD : in std_logic;        
 Address : out signed(31 downto 0); -- output
 CLK,RESET : in std_logic);      -- clock and reset
end component;






 signal reset                   : STD_LOGIC;
 signal WR                          : STD_LOGIC ;
 signal SD                              : STD_LOGIC ;
 signal counter_en                      : STD_LOGIC ;
 signal RAM_in                          : SIGNED(31 downto 0);

signal RAM_out               : SIGNED(31 downto 0);

signal SIN                   : SIGNED(31 downto 0);
signal COS                   : SIGNED(31 downto 0);

signal r_n                     : SIGNED(31 downto 0);
signal theta_n                 : SIGNED(31 downto 0);
signal Etheta                   : STD_LOGIC ;

signal Adresse                : SIGNED(31 downto 0);




begin




compt: COUNTER PORT MAP (
       counter_en => counter_en,                
       rn => r_n,
       thetan => theta_n,    
       Etheta => Etheta,
       SD => SD,
       CLK => clk,
       RESET => reset); 


MEM_SIN: SINGLE_PORT_ROM port map   (
        clk     => clk,
        addr    => conv_integer(theta_n),            --SUREMENT PB DE CONVERSION ICI!!
q       => SIN
    );

MEM_COS: SINGLE_PORT_ROM port map   (
        clk     => clk,
        addr    => conv_integer(theta_n),            --SUREMENT PB DE CONVERSION ICI!!
q       => COS
    );


calcul_adress: ADDRESS PORT MAP (
 sin => sin, 
       cos =>cos, 
       r => r_n,    
       theta => theta_n,    
      SD => SD,         
 Address => adresse, 
 clk => clk,
 RESET => Reset
);   


 --RAM: SINGLE_PORT_RAM port map (
--       clk     => clk,
--      addr    => conv_integer(adresse),
--      data    => RAM_in,
--      we    => WR,
--      q        => RAM_out 
--      );

Machine_etat: FSM port map (
      Clk           => CLK ,
        Reset_main      => Reset_main ,
        Conversion_en => Conversor_en,
        RAM_out => RAM_out,
        Etheta => Etheta,

        Reset           => reset,
        WR          => WR,
        SD          => SD,  
        counter_en          => counter_en,
RAM_in => RAM_in
);


end A;
```

BENCH_CONVERSOR

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;



    entity bench_conversor is
    end bench_conversor;

    architecture BEHAVIOR of bench_conversor is

    component CONVERSOR

    port(   
        CLK     : in STD_LOGIC ;
        RESET_Main  : in STD_LOGIC ;
        Conversor_en        : in STD_LOGIC; 
        Conversor_end : out STD_LOGIC) ;

    end component;

    -- inputs 


signal Conversor_en : std_logic;      
signal clk : std_logic;      
signal reset_main : std_logic;



    -- output

signal Conversor_end : std_logic;      


-- clock period definition

constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;



    BEGIN

 -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)

uut: CONVERSOR PORT MAP (

        CLK     => CLK,
        RESET_Main  => Reset_main,
        Conversor_en        => Conversor_en, 
        Conversor_end => Conversor_end
);   



-- Clock process definitions( clock with 50% duty cycle is generated here.
   clk_process: process
 begin
    clk <= '0';
    wait for clk_period/2;  --for 5 ns signal is '0'
    clk <= '1';
    wait for clk_period/2;  --for next 5 ns signal is '1'
 end process;

 -- stimulus process
   stim_process : process
begin

    wait for 50 ns;

  conversor_en <= '0';
  Reset_main <='1'; 


  wait for 50 ns;

  conversor_en <= '0';
  Reset_main <='1'; 

    wait; -- va attendre pour toujours

end process;

end BEHAVIOR;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using different libraries, which come with their own, incompatible, implementations of `std_logic`.

Remove the include of `IEEE.std_logic_arith.all` (and possibly also `IEEE.std_logic_signed.all`), and include `use IEEE.numeric_std.all` instead. The latter is the portable, standardized version, and is the one you should use for new designs.

You may have to convert some of your code though (haven't looked through it all), as you will no longer be able to do arithmetic with `std_logic_vector` for instance - you should use the `UNSIGNED` and `SIGNED` types instead, which it seems you are already doing for most of your signals.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that the problem of incompatible libraries would directly appear at compilation. As it didn't, I didn't check on it more then that...   I know what to do now :)

Comment: They didn't appear at compilation time because module (a) doesn't know anything about module (b) and vice versa. It's only when they are loaded in Modelsim and elaborated (think starting a C program against a missing DLL) that you discover they don't match...

Answer (score 5):

```
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
```

ARRGH!

Get rid of std_logic_signed as well as std_logic_arith throughout, and just use std_logic_1164 and numeric_std...

The other poster was almost right - std_logic is correctly defined (by _1164) but signed and unsigned are not (because of std_logic_signed as well as std_logic_arith)
BUT he was too polite about it... :-)

You have so many different incompatible libraries here that the entity ports are one type of signed and the component ports are another, incompatible, signed type!

There may be some remaining errors if you have mixed std_logic_vector and signed, but with only one library in use, the error messages should start making more sense...

One classic source of confusion is that if the compiler can find two or more definitions of something like "+" in two different libraries, it will regard them BOTH as hidden, rather than pick one of them at random and possibly get the one you didn't expect...

Comment: A couple more points looking through the code : you have used "conv_integer" from the evil packages : numeric_std calls it "to_integer" (a much better name, it tells you which direction the conversion is in!) Also (in counter) the reset assignments would be much simpler as "r <= (others => '0');" and the comparisons as "if theta /= 2 then ..."

Comment: I am also curious how well a 16 million bit data word works out in practice!

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious explanations, and for the reset tips ;) Things you don't think of too much when you learn yourself let's say...   I know what to do now to carry on!